# Multilanguage Website

Tags: i18n-l10n, external-scripts

I'm trying to run some script from Pinterest, to validate my site.

What's happenning is I need to write in Pinterest the url of my site, but my site redirects always like this : "XXX.com/es". How can I avoid that for this test made it by Pinterest.

I also can include on HTML file given by Pinterest but that would be the same, since again my website **adds the language** (=es) at the end of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your question is about a "multilingual" site, and not really about "multi sites". Consider editing your question (title, tags, etc) accordingly.

Moreover, your question is a variation of [these types of questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A39516%20detection%20%5Bmultilingual%5D), and that your issue is actually caused by a language detection issue (something you have not yet configured correctly in your site. Consider updating your question as appropriate. After doing so, I can also update my answer here, to actually pinpoint what kind of admin changes you might have to apply to achieve the desired result.

Based on the info provided in your question for now, I wonder what the DEFAULT language is that you specified within /admin/config/regional/language of your site. Could it be that it is "es"? If so, and if you also have enabled the "en" language, then change that default to "en" and retry again. Eventually, change the default language back afterwards, to whatever it was before (whenever your Pinterest script no longer requires you to (temporary) change that default language).

You may also want to check your configuration at *Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection*: the order should be 'URL, Default, User', and not something like 'Default, URL, User'.

Comment: Thanks for rectify my question, my bad.

The default language of my site is **/es** but If I change it to **en** as default, it will go always to **en**.

In that case I will have the same problem ... Because I need pinterest verify my whole site, not just one language ...

Comment: Ok, that's a little progress in sorting this issue out. I just added the last paragraph to my answer. Can you verify that also (+ provide feedback)?

Comment: Your last answer really helped me, thx so much :D

Comment: Eureka! Thank "you" too for confirming it helped ... and the accept and +1 of course. No other "multi language" challenges with Drupal? I start to have fun in remote debugging the dozens of issues I see being posted on Drupal.SE ... Like what about views results in specific languages?

Comment: For now I don't but as soon as I have one I'll let you know, btw great contribution to Drupal :) , take care, also can I add you as my mentor ?? Just wondering ...

Comment: Hm, thank you for the kind words and kudos. Sure regarding the "mentor" (that'd be an honor to me!). I'm curious a bit about "why, for what kind of things you noticed or so?". also: feel free to use my contact form or D.O (in my profile there), and/or eMail me where appropriate. What's your D.O profile?

Comment: It's "DarkteK" Ohh I saw that you created many modules, yes I'll email you anytime :D